# What is the word for when you say something like "I'm dying" but don't mean it?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm really have trouble even describing the definition of this word, but I saw a post somewhere that was talking about how people these days say things like, "I'm dying" or "I'm dead" or something like that but they obviously don't mean it. Like they are being extreme. This is truly murdering my brain right now. (Kinda like that.)

Comment: Are you asking the difference between "I'm dying" and "I'm dead"?

Comment: hyperbole hyperbole
[hahy-pur-buh-lee] 
Spell  Syllables
Synonyms Examples Word Origin
See more synonyms on Thesaurus.com
noun, Rhetoric.
1.
obvious and intentional exaggeration.
2.
an extravagant statement or figure of speech not intended to be taken literally, as “to wait an eternity.”.

Comment: Isn't it _melodramatic_ or _drama queen_?

Comment: Reminds me of the story of the boy who cried wolf. Look here: https://www.storyarts.org/library/aesops/stories/boy.html

Comment: Maybe just everyday exaggeration?

Answer (score 5):

**Histrionics**

> 2. (used with a sing. or pl. verb) Exaggerated emotional behavior calculated for effect. ([American Heritage, found at thefreedictionary.com](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/histrionics))

(I couldn't find my own interpretation of this word in any of the dictionaries I checked, but I think that your typical natural-born drama queen or prince doesn't always do it for effect.  Some people do it for more internal reasons.)

Example:

> I'm glad to be home.  I'm exhausted from one of my students and his histrionics.  I know perfectly well his jabbering about wanting to kill himself isn't true suicidal ideation, but I couldn't very well ignore it, could I?

Answer (score 4):

Hyperbole - exaggerated statements or claims not meant to be taken literally

I was looking for a word to reflect a comment to a new Snow Patrol album. 
"The album is that bad I would send it to anyone for free".
I know its not life or death but the album is the pits. You should hear it!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this word has a proper meaning by itself but it does in the context. Look at the following examples:

- You have been hiking, or working so hard and you need a break, then you can say "I'm dying" *which means you are tired, weary*.
- You have done something wrong and you are afraid your parents will tell you off, then you can say "I'm dead" *which means your parents will punish you*.